# How to do this in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

assume that I have the following obejct:

```
class title
{
    string Title;
    int id;
    // other information about title
 }

class person
{
   string Name;
   List<title> titles;
   // other information about person

}

List<Person> FindPersonsBasedOnTitle(List<Title> titles)
{
     List<Person> p=getPersons();

     // How to search P for all persons that have at least one title matched in titles?
}
```

How can I find the list of persons who have at least one title in input titles to this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Person> FindPersonsBasedOnTitle(List<Title> titlesToMatch)
{
   List<Person> p=getPersons();

   return p.Where( item => item.titles.Any( title => titlesToMatch.Contains( title ) )
          .ToList(); 
}
```

Note that this won't compile unless `titles` is public in `person`.